# best practice for string replacement in c#

Tags: c#, replace

I just wrote a console application to to replace a certain string within a large number of utf-8 coded files. I need to cover about 20 different cases of this string so I reduced my codesnippet to the necessary parts.
 The Code looks like this:

```
foreach (String file in allFIles)
{
    string text = "";
    using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(file))
    {
        text = r.ReadToEnd();
    }

    if (text.Contains(Case1))
    {
        string textCase1 = "";
        using (StreamReader rCase1Reader = new StreamReader(file))
        {
            textCase1 = rCase1Reader.ReadToEnd().Replace(Case1, Case1Const);
        }
        using (StreamWriter wCase1 = new StreamWriter(file, false, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            wCase1.Write(textCase1);
        }

        UsedFIles.Add(file);
    }
}
```

My problem is that if I try to replace a string that looks like this: `"partnumber: 58"` and there also is a string that looks like this `"partnumber: 585"`

My problem is that if the current string contains the desired substring and in addition a string that has a high similarity like `"partnumber: 58"` and `"partnumber: 585"`, my code will also replace the highly similar string.
Is there a way I can avoid this behavoir?

Comment: Use regular expressions. Paste some example of files.

Comment: what does the whole string look like?

Comment: You need to read the next character. Determine if it's a delimiter and then decide if you want to do the replacement.

Comment: Why do you read the text twice? For me, File.ReadAllText and File.WriteAllText seem a lot simpler.

Comment: Tip: If you need to replace 20 cases, then read once, replace al 20 and write once. Don't read/write for every case.

Comment: When you correctly find "partnumber: 58", what does the next character(s) look like? If that is a recognisable delimiter (space, semicolon, ...), add that to both search and replace.

Comment: There are about ~2100 files that have a diversified structure because the files originate from ~6 different interfaces. Some are JSON, some have a structure I've never seen before. But these namings seem to be equal in each of them. That's why I mentioned there are about 20 cases meaning all the same but with different structure.

Comment: @TheLax Solution strongly depends on the look of the data.

Answer (score 1):

Read the whole file, find the string you're interested in and then check the bit after it. Assuming the file has more to read.

```
    foreach (String file in allFIles)
    {
        string text = "";
        using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(file))
        {
            text = r.ReadToEnd();
        }

        int x = text.IndexOf(Case1);
        while(x > -1)
        {
            if (text.Length - x > Case1.Length)
            {
                string nextBit = text.SubString(x + Case1.Length, 1);
                if (IsDelimeter(nextBit))
                {
                    text = Replace(text, x, Case1, Case1Const);
                    x += Case1Const.Length;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                 text = Replace(text, x, Case1 Case1Const);
                 break;
            }
            x = text.IndexOf(Case1, x + 1);
        }

        File.WriteAllText(file, text);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Regex

```
new Regex(@"partnumber: 58$");
```

Comment: Why not use `string.Replace`? As James Barrass comments, if theres a common delimiter then its probably more efficient to use that

Comment: That regex will match both 58 and 585. The question specifically wants to avoid that.

Comment: That Regex is wrong. one it will match both and two you've added a double slash. http://regexr.com/3cik8 even removing the double slash it doesn't work http://regexr.com/3cikb

Comment: Still wrong ^ is the beginning of a string, you mean $

Comment: Assuming the file contains partnumber: 58 - An interesting item, partnumer: 585 - A boring item. Or anything else after the part number this is still wrong

Comment: How do you know how they look data? Maybe there isn't end of line?

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
var files = new[] { "File1.txt", "File2.txt", "File3.txt" };
// Where the key is the regex pattern to match and the value is the string to replace it with.
var patterns = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    { @"partnumber: \d\d", "FooBar" },
};

foreach(var file in files)
{
    string str = File.ReadAllText(file);
    foreach (var pattern in patterns)
        str = Regex.Replace(str, pattern.Key, pattern.Value);
    File.WriteAllText(file, str);
}
```

This example uses regex (regular expressions), the pattern `partnumber: \d\d` matches any strings that start with 'partnumber: ' and end in two digits. Regex is very powerful and you can use it to describe very specific cases you want to match so you can extend this for multiple patterns.